# php regex to get title

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I'm trying to strip content titles out of the middle of text strings. Could I use regex to strip everything out of this string except for the *title (in italics)* in these strings? Or is there a better way?

> Joe User **wrote a blog post called**
>   *The 10 Best Regex Expressions* **in the category** Regex.
>
> Jane User **wrote a blog post called**
>   *Regex is Hard!* **in the category** TechProblems.

I've tried to come up with a regex expression to cover this, but I think it might need two. The trick is that the **text in bold** is always the same, so you could search for that, like this:

regex: delete everything before and including **wrote a blog post called**

regex: delete **in the category** and everything after it.

Comment: so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: horrible, amateur regex code that should not see the light of day. :-) correct answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^.+ wrote a blog post called (.+) in the category .+$
```

So:

```
preg_replace( '|^.+ wrote a blog post called (.+) in the category .+$|', '\1', $str );
```

^ is start of line
.+ is some characters (one to many)
(.+) same, but the content will be available in \1, for preg_replace()
$ is the end of line